# IFTTT Maker service and CloudMQTT

Tags: mqtt, iot, ifttt

I am using CloudMQTT.com as MQTT broker. Now, for some reasons, I need to use Maker service of IFTTT.com and needs to send message on topic created on CloudMQTT.

Problem is that Maker service only supports HTTP(s) end points and does not support MQTT, to my understanding. I am not able to find the HTTP(S) endpoint for CloudMQTT.com, which I can use in Maker service to connect both of them.

Any clue if connecting Maker and CloudMQTT is possible through any http(s) endpoint of CloudMQTT OR is it not doable ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Writing your own HTTP to MQTT service should be relatively simple

Comment: You are right. I can do that but I specifically wanted to know if CloudMQTT provides any endpoint. Thanks for posting the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I am understanding your question correctly, you want to directly send data from IFTTT to CloudMQTT using HTTP without using a bridge of some sort.

As far as I can tell that is not possible. The only thing the CloudMQTT HTTP API handles is user management (https://www.cloudmqtt.com/docs-api.html) and I have not found anything else in the documentation that suggests you can publish to a CloudMQTT topic over HTTP.

What you need is a bridge between IFTTT and CloudMQTT which will take in an HTTP Post and spit out MQTT. That would be pretty easy to write but I think there are a few ready-made solutions out there. I haven't used it but Ponte (http://www.eclipse.org/ponte) looks promising.

For inspiration here is an approach using Home Assistant and Heroku to create an IFTTT to CloudMQTT (https://home-assistant.io/blog/2017/03/28/http-to-mqtt-bridge/). However, you should be able to write a simple bridge and deploy it on Heroku... they even have a CloudMQTT add-on available (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cloudmqtt)... or something similar.

Comment: Thanks blp. I have written the http to mqtt bridge using AWS Lambda and AWS API Gateway. Yes, Ponte is a good option but since I was looking for something serverless, I used AWS lambda. Thanks once again.